# How can I filter, or have multiple options, for a generic function?

Tags: swift, generics, generic-constraints

I have a function that is taking in a value, which I then send to NSUserDefaults to store in its Property List.

```
func store<T>(value: T, key: String) -> Bool {
  // send key, value to NSUserDefaults
}
```

How can I set up generic constraints so that the value can only be one of the possible types accepted for the property list?

I was thinking something like:

```
func store<T>(value: T, key: String) -> Bool where T:NSString OR T:NSData OR T:Etc{
  // send key, value to NSUserDefaults
}
```

which of course does not work.

Comment: Assuming your Bool return indicates success/failure, couldn't you simply use a guard/else statement to test the type?

Comment: I'd like a compiler error if the function is used with the wrong type

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom protocol for all the types you want to allow to persist:

```
protocol CustomProtocol {}

extension NSString: CustomProtocol {}
extension NSData: CustomProtocol {}
// etc.


func store<T>(value: T, key: String) -> Bool where T: CustomProtocol {
    // send key, value to NSUserDefaults
}
```